# problem of date conversion from english to french

Tags: python, time, strftime

I try to convert a date in english (2019-10-07) in french (07/10/2016)

I try

```
dat = '07/10/2019'
dat = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but got the result '2019-10-16' instead of '2019-10-07'

Comment: Because 16th is today's date and you are not converting the above date in your second line

Answer (score 0):

using `datetime` you can decide the format in which the source date is provided, and the target format you want.

```
from datetime import datetime

dat = '07/10/2019'
datetime.strptime(dat, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

`out[6]: '2019-10-07'`

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` needs a time/date to convert, and it will use the *current* date and time if you don't provide one. The previous value of `dat` is not relevant - this information is not seen by `strftime`.

You need to provide the time information that `strftime` will format, as a tuple that you can get by *parsing* the original string. For this, use `strptime` (f for format, p for parse).

So:

```
dmy = '07/10/2019'
ymd = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.strptime(dmy, '%d/%m/%Y'))
#                    ^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^
#                    output schema                  input schema
# now ymd is '2019-10-07'
```

(Or you can use the `datetime` module as in the other answer. This way, the parsing gives you an object, which has a *method* to format back - so you can write the whole operation "in order" on the line. But the general principle is the same: you need to parse, then format, and you need to specify the schema on each side.)

Comment: I understand better !

Answer (score 0):

with :

```
dat = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

you recover your actual date.

you need to make :

```
from datetime import datetime

dat = '07/10/2019'
dat = datetime.strptime(dat, '%m/%d/%Y')

print(dat.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
```